# Is there a solution to "object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string"?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I searched the Internet for some Solutions but none of it works and I can't find out why. I'm new to PHP and MYSQL/MyAdmin so I really don't understand what I did wrong.

I've already tried several commands and "while $row = $result->fetch_array()" and stuff like that.

```
$Word = "SELECT Word FROM RandWord WHERE Number = '$Number'";
$Word = mysqli_query($data, $Word);
echo $Word;
$Amount = count($Word);
```

I want it to Output the "Count($Word);" for me, but it can't even echo because it can not be converted into a string. I want to see the word and use it.

Comment: echo $Word; <-- this is causing the error

Comment: Yeah I know hat, but it can't Output at all since it cannot be converted into a string, which is my Problem.

Comment: $Word = "SELECT Word FROM RandWord WHERE Number = '$Number'";
$Word = mysqli_query($data, $Word);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    foreach($row as $value) echo "<td>$value</td>";
}
dont know if it helps

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on string in /users/hangmanbr/www/Playing.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /users/hangmanbr/www/Playing.php on line 9 /// Well sadly, it did not

Comment: can you try change $result->fetch_assoc() => $Word->fetch_assoc()?

Comment: Yeah it perfectly worked. Thank you, stranger! :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually fetch the results first, before you can use it. You are also vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, so use a prepared statement instead.

In your code `$Word` is a result-object, which holds information - but you need to use a fetching method to retrieve the data first. `count()` in PHP is only usable on arrays (or on objects, but not that object which you get from `mysqli_query()`).

```
$query = "SELECT Word FROM RandWord WHERE Number = ?";
$stmt = $data->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $Number);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($word);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $word;
}
$stmt->close();
```

If you want it to be a count of each word, you have to run a query using the MySQL function `COUNT()` instead.

```
$query = "SELECT Word, COUNT(Word) as cnt FROM RandWord WHERE Number = ? GROUP BY Word";
$stmt = $data->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $Number);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($word, $count);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $word." has count ".$count;
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /users/hangmanbr/www/Playing.php on line 12
CAMP // It tells me the word "CAMP" but how can I get rid of this error message?

Comment: @HelpNeeded Can you edit the question and add what your code looks like now?

Comment: That error doesn't match the exact code in my answer, you're doing something different. There's one placeholder, one type definition and one value.

Comment: @HelpNeeded You replace the entire query part of your code with these prepared statement. There will be no `mysqli_query()` before it (for this particular query anyways). The error you described in your first comment does not correspond to the code given in my answer, so you must be doing something different.